# when to use had had in a sentence?

Tags: tense, past-perfect

> The project also had had a tangible demonstration impact.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? The event occurred a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

It would be grammatical in the right context.  'had had' is [past perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_perfect), referring to the past of the past, or something that happened earlier than a past tense context.  A suitable past tense context could be:

> Last year, the director *requested* an increase of funding.  She *said* the research **had begun** to yield interesting results.  The project also **had had** a tangible demonstration impact.

*italics = past tense, time -x*, **bold = past perfect, time -x-y**